what is the 'this' keyword in the .on method's callback function of leaflet library?
Im curious because the this keyword inside of JavaScript's event handler function is the element in which the .eventListener() is attached to. And the .on() method of leaflet library is similar to .eventListener() but if it's just a regular method my guess is that inside the .on() method's event handler function the this  keyword will be undefined

this in the callback of a Leaflet on function is usually the instance of the object that you're using on with, like Map or Marker, unless you use the context argument to point the this keyword to a different object. See the source code for more info on how Leaflet implements this.

The magic actually happens here. See also Function.prototype.call()

Remember that functions that take callback arguments can decide what (if anything) to pass as the this context. E.g. in jQuery, .map() and .each() set it to the current element in the iteration.
